# concat images and resize at the same time using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am combining images into a single video file.

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat  -safe 0 -i "input.txt" -pix_fmt yuv420p "output.mp4"
```

inside the input.txt file there are the entries:

```
file 'one.jpg'
duration 0.5
file 'two.jpg'
duration 0.246
file 'three.jpg'
duration 0.233
```

etc etc

I know the image size is 1024x720

and I want them resized to 352x768

Is it possible to do it at all in one command? I have seen now to do it in 2 commands but that is no good for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the command you provided with the `scale` option added.

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i "input.txt" -vf "scale=352:768" -pix_fmt yuv420p "output.mp4"
```

man ffmpeg:

```
            _______        _____________        _______        ________
           |       |      |             |      |       |      |        |
           | input | ---> | deinterlace | ---> | scale | ---> | output |
           |_______|      |_____________|      |_______|      |________|
```

Add video filter `-vf` with the scale parameters you require: `"scale=352:768"`

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining it

Comment: Thanks will test this now

Comment: Tried to explain what I added, but there isn't much, you were close. It worked for me, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Excellent it worked! Thank You!